# How make the Google Cloud Storage Bucket as a static-website Visible With and Without www?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hello to everybody after all correct configurations as I followed at the "Documentation of Google Cloud Storage - Configuring a Bucket as a Static Website" my bucket it work as a website but the problem is about the prefix WWW in fact when I visit the bucket http://www.pieropretti.net I can see the content of the public bucket, but if I visit (from the browser Chromium version 42.0.2281.0 (64-bit) and same problem from the browser FirefoxESR 31.4.0 (Tor Browser 4.0.3) without the prefix WWW I receive the error server not found. This is the screenshot of the domain name DNS configuration in the picture here [http://tinyurl.com/ncoc9y5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcEH1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From DNS records I notice that you are on OVH, if it is you can use the [OVH Redirection Technology](http://help.ovh.com/FreeRedirection) to redirect from naked to WWW.

If you are on other maintainers don't worry all offers service like OVH for redirect the naked to the www.

Comment: Thanks Aqquadro I solved the easy problem of this task with your Answer here. I want also say that in an Stack Exchange task someone advice to solve the naked-redirection with ***such a spam service*** **Wwwizer free naked domain redirect** I will be very very careful with Wwwizer because someone malicious migth down the track so is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

"www.pieropretti.net" and "pieropretti.net" are different domain names, and thus also correspond with different buckets. If you want to serve content from "pieropretti.net", you will need to create a bucket named exactly "pieropretti.net" in the same way you created the "www.pieropretti.net" bucket.

From what I can see, the DNS setting for "pieropretti.net." doesn't seem to have a CNAME, despite what your panel is telling you. Perhaps it just hasn't propagated to me yet.

Comment: It's odd. When I look up your domain. grandpa1930.com, on a site like http://ping.eu/nslookup/, I don't see any CNAME records.

Answer (score 0):

For top-level domain name we can't add CNAME, we can add A record, so I goto my Terminal and ping c.storage.googleapi.com to get the IP address, then I use the IP address to add into the A record, it works for me, just not sure whether it's an appropriate way to do it this way or not, but it just works for me.

Comment: Following this, i also had create an additional bucket with top-level domain only. Within that i placed index.html which does meta redirection to my sub-level domain (www).

Comment: Problem with this approach is your top level redirect will vanish whenever Google changes the IP for c.storage.googleapis.com. You would have to ping it constantly, and adapt the value of your a record accordingly - or your customers will take notice before you and complain that their pages are gone, giving you bad rep.